# How to connect any server using ssh in Cypress.io?

Tags: cypress

In cypress, i tried to connect application backend(want to connect as ssh username@hostip password) using "cy.exec" but couldn't get success. 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Suraj. What exactly do you want to achieve using SSH from Cypress?

Comment: Thanks for reply, looking to see backend logs and running commands, for that need to connect to ssh

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense for Cypress to be doing this kind of work.

1) it's not designed to calling remote systems and 
2) How long will these things take? What if they don't respond in time?

I presume that you are wanting to check that front end actions have been completed in the back end - probably better to get cypress to drive the UI to look for evidence of success, even if it means logging in as a different user to get it.

Although Cypress won't let you log in to a different system in the same test. You could possibly write other tests to access the other systems